# Controlling Raspberry pi3 Wirelessly with HTML (Lighttpd)

Tags: rpi.gpio, wireless, script, lighttpd

I've been working on a Obstacle avoidance robot using Ultrasonic and IR sensors.

The scope of my project is to execute my program over the air.

- Control the robot's movement using mouse or touch screen.
- Execute the obstacle avoidance program

The program for "robot movements" is written in very basic cgi scripts (just by controlling the GPIO pins and thus the respective motors)

```
gpio -g write 13 1
```

The second program is written in Python.

My Question :

1. Can a HTML page directly execute .py files?
2. If not please guide some tutorials about .cgi programming or Python scripts in such a file. Or just how should i proceed, do i need to learn PHP or HTML programming?

Basically This is the code, making a button.

```
<button style="height: 75px; width: 75px" onclick="forward()"><img style="height: 65px"src="/images/forward.png"></button>
```

This is suppose to call the function below, but the .py file is not executed

```
function forward()
{
xmlhttp.open("GET","cgi-bin/forward.py",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I'm new to this kind of over the air controlling. Any help would be appriciated

Comment: You've not mentioned what your "movements" CGI have been written in: how do you control the GPIO? If it has a `system()`-like command can you use that to start (or stop?) your python script as a background process? Beware though, using `system()` is frowned upon in some circles (**EDIT**: one [expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395633/why-is-it-bad-to-use-system-in-linux-programming) on why it's frowned upon)

Comment: It is written as a Script CGI file. Wiring Pi GPIO access library

'gpio -g write 5 0'  (Which basically means then give a logic 0 to pin 5)

Should i post the code to make things more clean?

Comment: That's OK, I misunderstood your question and thought you had the "movements" stuff already working from the web server and wanted to expand it to also run your Python script. I now see that the "movement" part runs of the Pi's interface, not on the web server. Sorry.

Comment: the basic movements do work. "gpio -g write 5 0" is written with the normal #!/bin/bash . I'm using the wiring PI library to directly access the GPIO pins.


The problem is when i want to run a .py file. It doesn't execute the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for a way to control your robot remotely via a browser, one framework to look at is **node.js**.

**Node.js** is a java-script runtime environment that allows you to run java-script code both on browser and server side.

There are [excellent tutorials from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_raspberrypi.asp) on how to control/read the GPIO-pins of the Raspberry Pi via node.js.

Comment: The server is actually established. I can access the web page from the Web browser and execute .cgi files as well. It's just that i'm not able to execute .py files. 

I do not know scripting language to an extent that i can write the whole pro gram i wrote in Python in Scripting language

Comment: I got that. I wanted to point you to an alternative to your AJAX calls. Node.js is not hard to learn IMO.

Comment: Thank you the response. I found your answer helpful. It's either Node.js or Flask for Python. Which can run the back-end server.

Comment: Best of luck with your project!